# writeJSON groovy writes only first value to file

Tags: groovy

Below is my jenkins groovy script to read data and write as json file.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
def arn = ""
def name = ""
def os = ""
pipeline {
    agent any
stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps {
            script{

                def ret = sh(script: 'aws devicefarm list-devices', returnStdout: true)
                def jsonObj = readJSON text: ret
                def currentVersion = "13.0"
                def values = currentVersion.split('\\.')
                def json_str = ""
                for(String item: jsonObj.devices) {
                    os = item.os
                    if(!os.contains("\\.")) {
                        osV = os + ".0"
                    } else{
                        osV = os
                    }
                    def osValues = osV.split('\\.')
                    if(values[0].toInteger() <= osValues[0].toInteger()) {
                        name = item.name

                        def data = [
                            name: "$name",
                            os: "$os",
                        ]
                        json_str += JsonOutput.toJson(data)  
                    }
                }
                def json_beauty  = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)
                writeJSON(file: 'message124.json', json: json_beauty)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But here, it only saves the first value. Not all the values. Could you tell me where I am wrong here

Comment: Wouldn't the final `json_str` be a non-JSON-y thing like `"[name: ..., os: ...][name: ..., os: ...]"` instead of JSON of an array of objects as it's written currently?

Comment: How can we do that ? @DaveNewton

Comment: Have the string be an array of objects instead?

Comment: Could you please give a try as I am new to this @DaveNewton

Comment: Show the expected Json result

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you actually want to end up with, but I *think* you want a JSON file containing the items where OS is greater than a magic number.

It's helpful to provide enough data to duplicate the problem, and eliminate everything that isn't directly related. I think what you want is something like this:

```
jsonObj = [
  devices: [
    [ os: '3', name: 'Name 1'],
    [ os: '10.2', name: 'Name 10.2'],
    [ os: '7', name: 'Name 7'],
    [ os: '3', name: 'Name 3'],
  ],
]

values = ['5']

def normalizeOs(os) {
  os.contains(".") ? os : "$os.0"
}

def shouldSkip(normalizedOs) {
  osValues = os.split('\\.')
  values[0].toInteger() > osValues[0].toInteger()
}

selected = []
for (item: jsonObj.devices) {
  os = normalizeOs(item.os)
  if (shouldSkip(os)) continue

  selected.push([name: item.name, os: os])
}

json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(selected)
println(json)
```

Outputs:

```
[{"name":"Name 7","os":"7.0"},{"name":"Name 10.2","os":"10.2"}]
```